# Gertboard or similar for Raspberry Pi 2?

Tags: gertboard

I was reading some Raspberry Pi-related magazine the other day which strongly recommended a Gertboard because it makes it easier to work with motors, etc. From what I can tell, the board was designed for the original Raspberry Pi and is now discontinued.

Is something like the Gertboard still recommended for the Pi 2, or is it not really necessary? What newer alternatives are there, if any?

Comment: Despite the "answer" below, `Gertboard` is still available (from Element14, its original distributor), and quite usable with Pi2. It only has 26 pin GPIO connector (as do the PIFace boards), so doesn't make all the pins on newer Pi readily accessible, but is still an excellent development tool, with good support software and inbuilt protection for GPIO.

Comment: @Milliways Until someone buys all 3,800 pieces left.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need a Gertboard or similar to work with motors.

From memory the Gertboard was actually a poor choice for hobbyists as it could not be used to power typical hobby motors (minimum voltage was too high).

There are plenty of simple motor driver boards such as modules based on the [L298N](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/351540901700) and the [L9110S](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/351448375527) which are well suited to low power DC and stepper motors.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Yeah, it's available. It's over here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/gertboard-is-here/</s>

Take note that this product is [already phased out](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/11773). You may have some luck on eBay.

Instead of the Gertboard, you will want [PiFace](http://www.piface.org.uk/) instead.